# How to modify wordpress comment form

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to insert wrapper inside the wordpress comment form. Also I need to add classes to the textarea, input field and also I need to add another input fields in the standart wordpress comment form. For now I'm trying the following in my functions.php but nothing is changing, Can someone help?

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'crb_custom_fields', 2 );
function crb_custom_fields() {
$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
$req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

$custom_fields =  array(
    'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'crb' ) .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

    'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'crb' ) .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

    'url' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'crb' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
    '" size="30" /></p>',

    'comment_field' =>  '<p class="field comment-form-comment"><label for="comment" class="hidden">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) .
    '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true">' .
    '</textarea></p>',
);

return $custom_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing two parameters in the filter hook but when you define your function you're not actually passing any parameters at all.

```
[...]

  add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'crb_custom_fields', 10, 1 );
  function crb_custom_fields( $fields ) {

[...]
```

Use the above instead. I've set the priority to 10 (the default) and the number of arguments to 1. You can leave this out if you'd like, but it let's you be a little more verbose with your settings.

I've also added the `$fields` parameter that is passed to the function when called back. This is an array which holds the HTML of the contact form. So you can change your actual code to the following and you should start to see results.

```php
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'crb_custom_fields', 10, 1 );

function crb_custom_fields( $fields ) {

$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
$req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

$fields =  array(
    'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'crb' ) .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

    'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'crb' ) .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

    'url' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'crb' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
    '" size="30" /></p>',

    'comment_field' =>  '<p class="field comment-form-comment"><label for="comment" class="hidden">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) .
    '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true">' .
    '</textarea></p>',
);

return $custom_fields;

}
```

This filter then alters the appearance (*the HTML*) of what the [`comment_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) function prints out. It's a very customisable function through hooks. I'd recommend reading the documentation for more information about. The [`comment_form_default_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_default_fields/) hook docs are useful too.